# use IP depended rule in .htaccess to password protect a web folder

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, password-protected

i use following code in .htaccess file to usr/psw protect a web folder. However i want to protect this folder only if its accessed outside of 192.168.178.*
How can i do this?

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET POST >
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by replacing 'require valid-user' with the following lines:

```
require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.178.0/24
Satisfy Any
```

Edit: You have to add:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: i checked this, but it doesn't work. the folder can be accessed from outside the LAN

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten some part of the configuration. - See my edit.